# Retrieving an android colors.xml from artifactory in build.gradle before building

Tags: android, gradle, node-modules, artifactory

I'm new to gradle scripting and I'm trying to do something simple. There is an android colors.xml in an artifactory repo inside a tarball. All i want to do is configure gradle so that before it builds it gets that file from the repo (if its changed) and copies it to my android module's res/values/colors.xml. I can do that with npm install  on the command line but dont know how to run that from within build.gradle. My first stab is this in my module's build.gradle.

```
task getResourceTokens(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "/Users/cbattle/Dev/DesignTokenTest"
    executable 'npm'
    args = ['install https://artifactory-lvs.corpzone.internalzone.com/artifactory/.../token-tester-0.0.7.tgz']
    doLast {
        println "Executed!"
    }
}

task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    from '/Users/cbattle/node_modules/.../colors.xml'
    into '/Users/cbattle/Dev/DesignTokenTest/atoms/src/main/res/values'
}

copyFiles.dependsOn(getResourceTokens)
preBuild.dependsOn(copyFiles)
```

This fails with

```
Execution failed for task ':atoms:getResourceTokens'.
> Process 'command 'npm'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have the proper credentials in my .npmrc file. It works if I just use the command line manually. Its not clear why this fails.

I also have https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin installed so it may be possible to use that instead. But the above should work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For whatever reason it seems that the Exec task can not run npm. Instead I installed the handy [NodePlugin](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin) and used this.

```
task getTokens(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['install', 'https://artifactory-lvs.corpzone.internalzone.com/artifactory/.../token-tester-0.0.7.tgz']
}
```

That worked like a charm!